# Angular error in angular calendar year view

Tags: angular

Error: node_modules/angular-calendar-year-view/lib/angular-calendar-year-view.component.d.ts:6:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service' or its corresponding type declarations.
readonly style: import("@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service").SafeStyle;

Comment: Which Angular version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

seems like some dependency is missing can you check in your node modules if this is installed `@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service`

Answer (score 0):

It might have renamed or moved to another package like in Angular 12 it has been renamed to @angular/platform-browser/platform-browser/platform-browser.d.ts. Earlier it was @angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service

```
            export declare class Safe {
              private sanitizer;
              constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer);
              transform(style: any): import("@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser").SafeStyle;
              static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Safe, never>;
              static ɵpipe: ɵngcc0.ɵɵPipeDeclaration<Safe, "safeHtml">;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, just follow the error path

```
ERROR in node_modules/angular-calendar-year-view/lib/angular-calendar-year-view.component.d.ts(5,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service'.
```

in your code editor, You will find this line showing error

```
"readonly style: import("@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service").SafeStyle;"
```

Comment this whole line and paste under this commented line

```
readonly style: SafeStyle;
```